# Retrieve the WMS Request URL of a Geoserver layer on button click

Tags: geoserver, wms, gsconfig

I have some Geoserver layers, which are displayed using leaflet or geoexplorer.
What I need is to add a button, which onclick gets the WMS url for this layer.

Using the developers tools of Chrome, I can see the WMS request. I could try to build the URL by concatenating all the different parameters.

I wonder if there is another more elegant way to accomplish this. I was checking the gsconfig library but the get_layer and getresource functions don't think they return the WMS request URL.

Any ideas?

Comment: It all starts from the client: it builds the GetMap request by the BBOX of the map view with layers which user have selected. WMS server gets the request and sends the map. Therefore you must take the request from your client: "this is the request I am going to send" or "this was the request I sent".

Comment: When you say the WMS URL for this layer, do you mean the GetMap request that generated the image that you can see in the browser, or the GetMap request to show the full extent of the layer, or something else?

Comment: @nmtoken I mean the WMS URL which generated the image (the GetMap request)

Comment: So your client already has the URL. It had to create it to make the request. you don't need to build it again, just access the​ variable in your Leaflet code.

Comment: @nmtoken Do you have any solution for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856601/how-to-fetch-the-url-of-specific-geoserver-layer-by-switching-radio-button